# python syntax: how to return 0 instead of False when evaluating 0

Tags: python, syntax, return, return-value

For an assignment we were asked to define a fibonacci function, which I accomplished with this:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n < 2:
        return n
    return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

However, I have seen recursive functions, such as the factorial function, defined in a one line return statement like so:

```
def factorial(n):
    return n > 1 and n * factorial(n-1) or 1
```

So, I attempted to apply the same to my fibonacci function. After several attempts, I got it to work for all tested cases except when s = 0, in which case it returns False when it should return 0. Here is where I am:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    return ((n == 0 or n == 1) and n) or (n > 1 and (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)))
```

I understand that python evaluates 0 to False, so how would I have python return zero instead of False when n is 0 while maintaining the current length/structure of the code? Is that even possible?

Also, is this style of creating a function (recursive or otherwise) more or less desirable/pythonic than the textbook version? (I would imagine not just because of readability)

To be clear, I have satisfied the requirements for the assignment, and for personal knowledge only, I would like a clearer understanding of what is happening in the return statement.

Comment: are your requirement to write a _recursive_ fibonacci function, or just _a_ fibonacci function? because a recurisve implementation has a very bad (exponential) runtime, whereas a non-recurisve usually is linear. and a _pythonic_ thing would probably be a generator yielding the fibonacci sequence...

Comment: @mata: this assignment was aimed at illustrating the concept of recursion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `x and y or z` idiom doesn't work if `y` is [falsy](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations). You can swap the condition to make it work nonetheless:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    return n >= 2 and fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2) or n
```

However, as of Python 2.5 (released 6 years ago), we have proper [conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308) and don't need the `and/or` hack any longer:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    return n if n < 2 else fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

Now this has an exponential runtime complexity. If you want to be efficient, use the `O(n)` algorithm:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    a, b = 0, 1
    for _ in range(n):
        a, b = b, a + b
    return a
```

Or even write a generator to yield all the numbers and only take as much as you need.

Comment: Note that people used to use the `x and y or z` thing before `y if x else z` was introduced, in Python 2.5, because of this problem with that idiom and because it was ugly as hell anyway.

Comment: Yes guys, I assumed that everyone would use something above 2.5 by now :) Made it clear, though.

Comment: What's falsy?  Is that like kinda(False)

Comment: @jgritty: Anything that is considered False in a boolean context in Python, like `False`, `0`, empty collections, objects that override `__nonzero__` to return false, ...

Comment: OK, I thought so, but the idiom does work if y is 0, which is kinda(False) or falsy though. e.g. (0 or 0) == 0

Comment: @jgritty `0 or 0` is `0` because the second thing is `0`. `True and 0 or 'oops'` will evaluate to `'oops'`.

Comment: @jgritty: Yes, but `0 or False` is `False`, which is why the `and/or` hack to implement conditional expressions doesn't work. You'd need something like `(x and (y,) or (z,))[0]`, which is even fuglier.

Comment: Are either of your examples preferable to the textbook version, ie my original function? And why?

Comment: Interesting stuff.  Needs some very explicit unit tests or something.  I tend to write much more verbose code anyway.

Comment: @Verbal: No, for clarity I'd go with the explicit `if: / else:` in this case. The examples were just to show you how it could be done in one line if necessary (and also to inform you that `x and y or z` should not be used).

Comment: @jgritty: It's no longer a problem for nearly 6 years now. Who wants to use Python 2.4 anyway?

Comment: Not questioning your answer just wanted to get a feel for what proper style should be. Thanks!

Comment: @Verbal: Yeah, please see my edit, you can do much better performance-wise, if you're interested in that as well.

Comment: We just covered iterative vs recursive efficiency. My understanding is that up to a certain value recursive efficiency is comparable to iterative. I also understand that generators are even more efficient iterators as they do lazy evaluations. I have questions regarding that too but I will leave that for another post. Very enlightening stuff...

Comment: @Verbal: Okay, have fun coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this makes it clearer:

```
def fibonacci(n):
    print ((n == 0 or n == 1) and n)
    print (n > 1 and (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)))
    return ((n == 0 or n == 1) and n) or (n > 1 and (fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)))


print 0 or False
print False or 0
```

Comment: print is my friend, I have learned so much doing that yet that idea eluded me on this one. Thanks!